# вопрос о списке в Android Studio

Tags: android

Хочу осуществить переход на новую Activity после нажатия на первый элемент списка, но выдает ошибку в последней строке с getApplicationContex, с чем это может быть связано?

```
 final String[] Spisok = new String[]{ "Что", "Как", "Для кого"};
private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Spisok);
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        if(position==0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            getApplicationContex.startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Comment: Приложите стактрейс ошибки

Answer (score 3):

Потому что это метод. Вы не поставили скобки. Исправьте на:

```
getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Букву `t` еще в context забыли написать